# Quercus:php on glassfish server

Tags: quercus

I am trying to run php on glassfish server using Quercus  and i get the following error on top of my page

NetBeansProjects/WebApplication1/build/web/q2a/qa-include/qa-index.php:512: Notice: $count is an undefined variable NetBeansProjects/WebApplication1/build/web/q2a/qa-include/qa-index.php:556: Notice: $themeclass is an undefined variable [qa_load_theme_class].

Did anyone have the same problem before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install newer version of [Quercus 4.0.7](http://forum.caucho.com/showthread.php?t=9434) and your problem will be solved!